# Can we display linq result in view without using model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I was trying to display the result without model(CLASS), I already have a department and Employee class, now to show their joined result I don't want to make another class which contains EmpName and Department Name property.

IN MODEL

```
 public class EmpDetails
    {     
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
         public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
}
 public class Department
{
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

IN CONTROLLER

```
  var q = (from ED in cc.EmpDetails
join DT in cc.Department
on ED.DepartmentID equals DT.DepartmentID
select new {
ED.Name,
DT.DepartmentName
});

ViewBag.ListData = q;
```

IN VIEW

> ERROR :: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

```
 foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListData)
        {
            <div>
                @item.Name
            </div> 
         <div>
                @item.DepartmentName
            </div> 
        }
```

I want it to be done without using model

Comment: I may be having so many queries in my project,so for each query do i need model

Comment: I'm not an expert with EF, but don't you have to invoke the query you defined, for example by adding .ToList()?

Comment: I think it might work without `.ToList()` since the foreach enumerates it. Did you try it, what error occured?

Comment: ERROR :: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Comment: _I don't want to make another class_ - why not? Why would you forgo strong typed binding, intellisense etc?

Comment: Why dont you want to use a Model? Just make the Linq Query static and call it directly in the View if you must

Comment: You can have anonymous projection from ef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
@model dynamic

<h1>List of Customers</h1>
<div>
  @foreach(var item in Model.Customers)
  {
    <h2>@item.CustomerID</h2>
  }
</div>
```

Sample Query

```
var query = from c in db.Customers
        join o in db.Orders
        on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
        orderby c.CustomerID ascending
        select new { 
            c.CustomerID,
            c.CompanyName,
            o.OrderID,
            o.OrderDate 
        };
```

Here, you are not selecting Customer objects (select c).

You are creating an anonymous type that has four properties - CustomerID, CompanyName, OrderID and OrderDate. Although this LINQ query works without any problem.

> but you can't pass anonymous types to an ASP.NET MVC view.

A recommended solution but again you need create an additional class. If you wish to avoid doing that for some reason, here also  ExpandoObject.

> You can store the realized data in an `ExpandoObject` and then pass it
>   to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    NorthwindEntities db=new NorthwindEntities();

    dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
    model.Customers = db.Customers.ToList();
    model.Orders = db.Orders.ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

See more details [here](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/4dc3f036-d621-4d60-ac31-8c5373a39229.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could select your values as an array of strings.

CONTROLLER - remember to use ToList() on the last line:

```
var q = from ED in cc.EmpDetails
        join DT in cc.Department
        on ED.DepartmentID equals DT.DepartmentID
        select new { ED.Name, DT.Departmentname };

ViewBag.ListData = (from l in select new string[] { Name, Departmentname}).ToList();
```

Then in your view reference your values using the array index.

VIEW:

```
foreach (string[] item in ViewBag.ListData)
    {
        <div>
            @item[0]
        </div> 
     <div>
            @item[1]
        </div> 
    }
```

Comment: hey firedude please give me the code for view,i am not able to iterate it.

Comment: ERROR : The array type 'System.String[]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' instead.

Comment: This code works for me.  Try shuffling the code around a bit - moving the ToList() etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you don't want to use model? You can try using ViewModel instead  , it is still like a model but it is use when you have specific data that you want to display on view. You can write a representation of  Department and Employment class like this

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class DepartmentEmploymentViewModel
    {
        public string departmentName { get; set; }
        public string employmentName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
var q = (from ED in cc.EmpDetails
join DT in cc.Department
on ED.DepartmentID equals DT.DepartmentID
select new {
ED.Name,
DT.DepartmentName
});

//collection of department and employment name
List<DepartmentEmploymentViewModel> dpVM = new List<DepartmentEmploymentViewModel>();

dpVM = q;
```

**View:**

```
@model projName.Models.DepartmentEmploymentViewModel 
foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>
                @item.Name
            </div> 
            <div>
                @item.DepartmentName
            </div> 
        }
```

Comment: can we directly do    dpVM = q; ?  please tell me how to cast this

Comment: ok i noticed that you join 2 tables so can you please let me know what is the type of q after retrieve from database?is it a list?

Comment: it is anonymous type,yes it's a list

Comment: @Avin I'd modified some of the codes. Please try and see if it works.

Comment: Thanku shawn but i am aware of this way,by creating a model class,thats what my question is without model class